# Как правильно написать правила в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, маршрутизация

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно описать правило в htaccess, чтобы "page" в адресной строке
https://oknaservice102.ru/aluminums/page/alyuminevye-okna не отображался. Ссылка должна иметь вид https://oknaservice102.ru/aluminums/alyuminevye-okna